# Parsing a number from a string with thousands seperators

Tags: java, string, numbers, string-parsing

i'm parsing out Long values from given String-s.

`Long.valueOf()` and `Long.parseLong()` wouldn't work - because such a String `str` is in the format 1,234,567 and can be surrounded by spaces.

I can work this by processing the String to get it to bare digits-- then parsing the value out. so - it would be something like

```
str.trim(); 
String tempArray [] = str.split(","); 
str = ""; 
for (String s:tempArray)
    str+=s;
```

however, there must be a better way of doing this. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) here, with appropriate [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). *US* locale would suffice here. You've to take care of whitespaces though.

```
String str = "1,234,567";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
System.out.println(format.parse(str.replace(" ", "")));
```

You can even use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) which is slightly more powerful. You can add any grouping or decimal separator:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);

System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse(str.replace(" ", "")));
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is possible :)

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll(",","");
```

For removing even spaces :

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll(",","").replaceAll(" ","");
```

And you can pass it to Long immediately

```
Long myLong = Long.valueOf(str.replaceAll(",","").replaceAll(" ",""));
```

Comment: might need to remove whitespace too since it "can be surrounded by spaces".

Comment: oops...I think I must've seen an early version of your answer! Looks good!

Comment: i like this - w/one note: str.replaceAll(",| ","") saves another iteration on str

Comment: As the first string in replaceAll is a regexp, you can use something like "[, ]" to avoid the second replaceAll call.

Answer (score 4):

The `replaceAll` method can remove your commas and `trim` removes white space:

```
Long.parseLong(str.trim().replaceAll(",", ""))
```

Comment: trim only removes leading and trailing whitespace

Comment: @BarbiePylon The question says that the string can be "surrounded by spaces", so `trim` is appropriate here.

Comment: I didn't take it so literally like that, but I suppose you've got a point!